# A PHP error was encountered when conditions are applied in model

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have tables

- table1(id, name)
- table2(id, name, active)

The field active in table2 contains value '0' or '1'

My relation in my model is

```
static $has_many = array(
        array('table2', 'conditions' => array('active = ?' => array(0)))
    );
```

Later I have to find all where

table2.active = '1'

But now I am getting error as:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: lib/Relationship.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for condition value should be scalar (string, number, boolean)

```
$has_many = array(
            array('table2', 'conditions' => array('active' => 0))
        );
```

You have to use array only when using **IN** condition in query only.